# Multiple assigment to variable in same line (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

how does this script works and why the variable b get 50 as its value and not 1

```py
a = 1
b = 50
b, b = a, b
print(b)
```

actual result: 50

Comment: Because the right-hand side is *fully evaluated* before the assignment. You can think of it as creating a tuple `(a, b) == (1, 50)` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b, b = a, b` is actually a tuple assignment, and it works from left to right.

`b, b = a, b` evaluates to `(b, b) = (1, 50)` which in turn is executed as

```
b = 1
b = 50
```